# Does the memory requirements for secondary Namenode is in the same range as that of Namenode? in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, namenode

I am working with hadoop, little bit curious about the memory requirements for secondary namenode... as compared with Namenode

Comment: _"...[Secondary NN] is usually run on a different machine than the primary NameNode since **its memory requirements are on the same order as the primary NameNode.**"_  https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsUserGuide.html#Secondary_NameNode

Answer (score 0):

They should be identical if you want a highly available system.  If you don't need high availability, and you are using a secondary node as a secondary node then you could reduce the requirements but I'd think in production you would not want that.  It also would not enable you to make good predictions about performance.

Comment: Secondary NameNode != Standby NameNode so OP doesn't ask about HA I guess.

Comment: I agree but if we are going to talk about Secondary nodes we should raise the conversation to be a more full conversation.

Comment: Sure, unless it trivializes the answer :)